# Which resistors and capacitors are on this HX711 board?

Tags: identification

I have this [HX711](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf) board. What model of resistors and capacitors are used here? I need similar the same mounted resistors and surface mount capacitors. I would be grateful if you drop the link to them.

[image: Photo of PCB]

Comment: @The Photon  I am not interested in the exact number. I'm interested in a model, a case. Where can I find similar resistors and capacitors. I could use in my circuits.

Comment: Please edit your question, then. What you wrote says "I need exactly the same mounted resistors and surface mount capacitors" so that's the question we're going to try to answer.

Comment: @The Photon yep/ I  edited

Comment: probably 0603 or 0805 packages for the resistors and capacitors. It's difficult to tell what size without it being in front of me.

Comment: Measure them with a digital caliper. If they are 0.06 x 0.03 inches, you are  looking for 0603s, If 0.08 x 0.05, you are looking for 0805s (most likely from the look of the PCB). If 0.12 x 0.06 inches, you are looking for 1206es.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing very critical on this board, all the precision is built into the Avia HX711 integrated circuit.

There are MLCC bypass capacitors and some resistors that could be 1% semi-precision types. The transistor is the most common PNP available in China, but most other common PNP types will work.

All very jellybean parts and can be bought anywhere. Compare the reference design board and schematic in the datasheet you linked.

[image]

Looks like they've increased the input filter resistors to 1.20K and the voltage divider for the power supply is 8.2K/20K for a nominal AVdd of 4.3VDC.

It's not possible to know the capacitor values by looking at them, but you can measure the size for the footprint and pull them off and measure the values if you need to (using a capacitance meter).

In fact, we know the SOT-23 package is 1.9mm between the leads and the IC package SOP-16 is 1.27mm between leads, so the passive parts are definitely 0805 footprint. (2.0 x 1.3mm).

Answer (score 2):

As originally posted, you asked,

> I need exactly the same mounted resistors and surface mount capacitors

It's not possible to tell the specific part number of a capacitor just by looking at it. You need access to the original design files (schematic and/or bill of materials) to get this information.

We can tell you the capacitors are multilayer ceramic capacitors, a category that includes millions of possible part numbers, from dozens of vendors, and with probably 12 orders of magnitude possible range of capacitance value.

The resistors' values can likely be decoded from the markings on them, for example "1201" likely indicates \$120\times10^1\$, or 1.2 kohms resistance. And the power handling is likely similar to other parts of the same size. But again there are dozens of vendors selling very similar resistors, so we can't give you an exact part number simply from looking at them.

Comment: I do not ask for exactly the same. You can name at least one that looks like this. Or what is the name of this model.

Comment: @user10360597, The question you asked said "I need exactly the same mounted resistors and surface mount capacitors" so that is the question I answered.

Comment: thanks for the information